# bash spaces in dir names using find cause linebreaks in ls

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ls

I have not been able to handle spaces in filenames

The script:
With find I select all directories, they are fed in ls for counting number of files in the directory

## The bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for adir2 in $(find . -type d);
do
        echo "[$adir2]"
        DIRCOUNT=$(ls -1A $adir2 |wc -l)
        if [ $DIRCOUNT -eq 0 ]; then
          echo $adir2 "is empty"
        fi
done
```

## Test set-up:

```
mkdir testdir
cd testdir
mkdir 01\ dir
```

**Running the script here**

## The result:

```
[.]
[./dir]
./dir is empty
[./01]
ls: cannot access './01': No such file or directory
./01 is empty
[dir]
dir is empty
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20

**Remark:**
The following doesn't work:

```
find /path/to/dir -empty -type d
```

All dirs are shown.
Apparently the empty property is not there.
The location is an external USB-drive with ext4 partition.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces  (i would probably cobble something together with prefer `find -print0` and `xargs -0`)

Comment: @MikaelÖhman The duplicate question did not really help me but your suggestions are definitely in the right direction, thanks! The code that works for me: 'DIRCOUNT=$(find . -type d -print0 | xargs --null ls -1A|wc -l)'. Next is assigning it to adir2 but that will do.

Comment: See also [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you wanted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -d '' adir2
do
        echo "[$adir2]"
        dircount=$(ls -1A "$adir2" | wc -l)
        if [ "$dircount" -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "[$adir2] is empty"
        fi
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Try to avoid using all-uppercase variables.

Comment: The only place I have a problem with this is that it incorrectly implies that `$'\0'` is different in any way from `''`; as bash uses C strings, and C strings can't contain NUL literals, they're _exactly_ the same.

Comment: Are there any situations in which they're not? If you run `s1=''; s2=$'\0'`, `[[ "$s1" = "$s2" ]]` is true, and `${#s1}` and `${#s2}` are both 0. How would you distinguish them?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I use `$'\0'` to be explicit about what the delimiter is. It's NUL characters. Using `''` relies on knowing that C strings end in `\0` and that `read -d` does an unconditional `delimiter[0]` lookup. I don't think it's good style to rely on it. `-d` says it wants a single character, so we should pass it one.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, ...both approaches have disadvantages, certainly. The problem with the explicit `$'\0'` is that implies to readers that it does something useful, and thus implies that bash _doesn't_ use C strings -- making it more likely that someone who's seen that code is going to be surprised when they can't store binary data in a regular string variable without corrupting it, f/e. I'd rather that reading code make someone look up what the real semantics actually are instead of making them think they already know and understand those semantics but be wrong.

Comment: Great, this one works perfect, finally, thanks!